# Can I use JSTL operations as statements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jstl

I have a `HashMap` retrieved from my `Controller` and I want to put all values inside a `javascript` array but I keep getting an *missing ) argument list* error.

I read that it was possible to use `JSTL` tags inside `javascript`.

Here is my code:

**EDITED**
Resolved using @Pointy suggestion to make value quoted.

```
<script>
 var schools = [];
 <c:forEach items="${requestScope.school_list}" var="school">  
            schools.push("${school.value}");
 </c:forEach>

 console.log(schools);
</script>
```

Any suggestions? Or is it a bad practice to mix `JSTL` and `javascript`?

Comment: So long as you clearly understand how that works, it's fine, though in this case it'd be a lot simpler to just dump out the array with a JSON tool and let it be parsed as a simple JavaScript array initializer. JSTL runs on the **server**, and by the time the page makes it to the browser it's all gone.

Comment: Those values you're adding to the array need to be quoted if they're strings; again that's something that a JSON encoder tool would do for you.

Comment: @Pointy Thank you, it went through. About the JSON encoder tool, is Ajax an example of that?

Comment: No, it'd be something like a JSTL/EL function you call. It's for serializing Java data structures into JSON, and that also works to create JavaScript object and array initializers because the syntax is a superset of JSON syntax.

Comment: @j.ian.le, what I personally like to do is, whenever I get a data using JSTL, I just use a hidden span and write the JSTL value there and whenever I need that value in script I simply get it by span id .